# Birman-Schwinger Principle

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

The Birman-Schwinger principle says that if $\Delta$ is the usual Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we consider the operator $H=-\Delta-V$ for a positive potential $V$, then, for any $\lambda>0$, the number of eigenvalues at most $-\lambda$ of this operator is the same as the number of eigenvalues at least 1 of the operator

$$ K_\lambda=V^{1/2}(-\Delta+\lambda)^{-1}V^{1/2}.$$

Can you suggest any source where this result is proved for $\lambda=0$?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is $(-\Delta)^{-1}$?

Comment: We can define it for example via $\mathcal{F}((-\Delta)^{-1}f)(x)=|x|^{-2}\mathcal{F}(f)(x)$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is just Fourier transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This runs into obvious technical issues. For example, $K_0$ will not be bounded (let alone compact) even for very nice $V$. So one also has to think about what exactly one wants to prove.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2134) discusses these issues. In particular, the Birman-Schwinger principle for $\lambda=0$ is stated in equation (1.6).